# Time series, density of measurement

Tags: r

I am measuring the daily duration (min) of a repeating event (E) over a course of 364 days.

```
ev1<-c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2.7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3.27, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 370.33, 1375.4, 
1394.03, 1423.8, 1360, 1269.77, 1378.8, 1350.37, 1425.97, 1423.6, 
1363.4, 1369.87, 1365.5, 1294.97, 1362.27, 1117.67, 1026.97, 
1077.4, 1356.83, 565.23, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 356.83, 
973.5, 0, 240.43, 1232.07, 1440, 1329.67, 1096.87, 1331.37, 1305.03, 
1328.03, 1246.03, 1182.3, 1054.53, 723.03, 1171.53, 1263.17, 
1200.37, 1054.8, 971.4, 936.4, 968.57, 897.93, 1099.87, 876.43, 
1095.47, 1132, 774.4, 1075.13, 982.57, 947.33, 1096.97, 929.83, 
1246.9, 1398.2, 1063.83, 1223.73, 1174.37, 1248.5, 1171.63, 1280.57, 
1183.33, 1016.23, 1082.1, 795.37, 900.83, 1159.2, 992.5, 967.3, 
1440, 804.13, 418.17, 559.57, 563.87, 562.97, 1113.1, 954.87, 
883.8, 1207.1, 1046.83, 995.77, 803.93, 1036.63, 946.9, 887.33, 
727.97, 733.93, 979.2, 1176.8, 1241.3, 1435.6)

ev2<-c(0, 369.3, 158.2, 347.7, 312.5, 265.47, 334.73, 420.83, 816.9, 
925.6, 926.33, 925.4, 917.57, 675.27, 0, 426.03, 860.03, 1041.43, 
947.8, 1076.83, 709.5, 1014.17, 660.3, 428.2, 718.03, 920.8, 
810, 528.53, 103.83, 300.37, 822.03, 662.13, 393.83, 622.47, 
994.13, 1034.07, 893.8, 643.37, 605.07, 360.97, 158.13, 0, 0, 
678.33, 347.67, 384.87, 495.9, 231.37, 443.23, 638.1, 559.53, 
354, 220.13, 210.4, 425.77, 159.5, 260.13, 1132.9, 77.67, 263.83, 
276.23, 63.6, 1.97, 0, 765.2, 403.03, 214.4, 550.63, 752.47, 
58.7, 475.1, 776.4, 53.87, 106.07, 63.23, 425.5, 461.4, 172.73, 
764.8, 53.27, 20.7, 322.8, 228, 36.07, 27.23, 0, 66.3, 389.77, 
705.23, 9.9, 739.3, 883.73, 0, 0, 347.9, 831.43, 0, 28.2, 4.37, 
596.67, 973.7, 26.33, 0.03, 5.93, 777, 918.43, 0, 54.57, 888.13, 
92.83, 98.13, 808.17, 310.5, 263.57, 248.13, 133.37, 138.37, 
14.73, 55.27, 7.17, 242.6, 206.5, 62.97, 8.67, 670.03, 215.77, 
101, 14.07, 440.33, 603.6, 28.27, 257.07, 64.4, 36.4, 506.17, 
333.3, 121.83, 566, 4.33, 192.83, 77.83, 101.3, 261.67, 15.03, 
298.67, 0.3, 616.4, 90.9, 250.87, 323.17, 36.5, 205.2, 205.3, 
110.67, 33.43, 613.43, 95.27, 3.9, 558.7, 650.83, 0, 179.7, 40.6, 
217.13, 48.23, 423.67, 33.9, 176.3, 139.93, 31.63, 0, 162.77, 
311.47, 22.2, 128.3, 0, 304.9, 281.4, 140.73, 131.8, 393.5, 48.63, 
18.17, 232.7, 294.87, 207.6, 317.13, 51.87, 262.57, 70.73, 9.57, 
480.57, 491.37, 27.03, 625.37, 364.4, 0, 79.93, 723.3, 231.57, 
56.93, 836.43, 713.57, 16.8, 2.23, 56.67, 307.87, 466.77, 270.1, 
143.63, 686.23, 703.77, 0, 167.87, 152.6, 237.97, 278.03, 190.7, 
554.03, 37.5, 177.2, 69.2, 119.13, 225.4, 471.23, 7.43, 273.5, 
75.57, 226.73, 141.17, 40.83, 217.33, 238.2, 15.1, 281.27, 244.03, 
0.83, 186.8, 165.53, 142.1, 121.53, 138.83, 103.5, 42.03, 64.27, 
132.07, 26.73, 150.97, 0, 239.9, 100.47, 95.9, 78.23, 90.73, 
172.7, 9.17, 79.77, 67.67, 2.87, 136.73, 362.1, 78.23, 409.37, 
38.9, 62.73, 459.1, 352.6, 17.43, 241.27, 193.1, 278.4, 124.73, 
256.53, 152.6, 247.03, 229.3, 16.5, 73.9, 0, 545.47, 157.5, 182.2, 
276.57, 76.8, 284.43, 2.83, 1.17, 272.57, 314.77, 98.8, 219.93, 
115.23, 121.77, 453.23, 261.73, 101.83, 381, 118.33, 328.23, 
344, 179.5, 16.7, 99.13, 202.97, 57.57, 83.13, 206.87, 425.27, 
130.97, 113.17, 12.07, 207.4, 77.5, 104.7, 59.77, 59.1, 166.6, 
121.2, 139.77, 96.4, 44.23, 262.6, 61.97, 173.2, 281.03, 27.77, 
91.33, 331.23, 142.73, 103.17, 155.7, 80.47, 52.7, 28.6, 56.67, 
257.23, 90.43, 19.43, 69.43, 358.6, 77.9, 15.07, 592.9, 597.27, 
16.83, 225.53, 176.67, 211.47, 159.83, 211, 187.27, 269.73, 27.1, 
421, 83.1, 11.1, 11.67, 253.1, 326.33, 74.33, 153.93, 12.03, 
70.9, 84.47)
```

Both individials (ev1, ev2) have approximately the same total duration of events, however the **temporal** "spread" is greater in ev2 and more "focused" in ev1

```
plot(1:364, ev1, type="l", xlab="Days", ylab="Daily Event duration", main="ev1")
plot(1:364, ev2, type="l", xlab="Days", ylab="Daily Event duration", main="ev2")
```

I would like to describe or quantify this **temporal** spread or aggregation of the daily event duration over time. Is there any standardized way to do this?

I was thinking something like: What is the minimum number of days that would account for x percent of the total event duration. For the above example this minimum days would be greater for ev2 than ev1. Is there any way to calculate this?

Any thoughts or references would be helpful.

Thanks a lot

Comment: This question might be better placed at: http://stats.stackexchange.com than here.

Comment: I pondered back and forth whether I should post this in Stats or in stackexchange. I decided to post this here because I present specific data and one of the questions is technical/programming ("..min number of days...")

Comment: There are a ton of ways in R to calculate your "min number of days to X%" .  Take a look at `quantile` and `ecdf` , or for small datasets like yours, silly things like `which(cumsum(sort(mydata)) > sum(mydata)* 0.1 ) `  (for 10%, obviously)

Comment: Carl: I don't need descriptives of the event duration (which one can obtain with what you mention). I want to get descriptives of the number of days needed till x percent of the total event duration. This is something totally different.

Comment: Actually, `which` in my example will give you  the *index* of the sorted day-values, which therefore tells you how many days (of the *sorted* list) it took to reach X% .    And certainly using `ecdf` or other tools to generate a distribution function will get you what you asked for.

Comment: Isn't all you want a standard deviation statistic? It has been a while since I've had a statistics class but I could have sworn there was way to use standard deviation (or something related to it) to get the type of answer your looking for. But that may only be with data that follows a bell curve. Standard deviation would at least get you an idea of how spread out the data is. And sorry but I have no idea what r is for all I know it was already mentioned just using a reference I'm not familiar with.

Comment: Carl: This is a time series (as in title). You cant change the sequence of the days.

Comment: Of course the simple answer to your question is to simply get the sum of the entire subset (lets start with ev1 and use the variable TotalSum) then incrementally add each value in the array to a partial sum variable and check that value against x% * TotalSum until you reach what you want then you know how many days from the start it takes to get to x%. Assuming that I understand your request and you want the x% criteria to be reached starting from the start of the data instead of the minimum point somewhere in the middle of the data set. Sorry again but I don't even know what r is no code.

Answer (score 3):

If you want the "time" to be the index then maybe it would be easier to work with a representation that explicitly recognizes that:

```
dfrm <- data.frame(tm <-1:364, ev1=ev1, ev2=ev2)
```

Since you are really interested in the "density" of the index ("tm") values, use the weights argument to density:

```
 ev1dens <-  density(dfrm$tm, weights=dfrm$ev1/sum(dfrm$ev1), from=0, to=364, n=364)
 plot( ev1dens, lwd=5)
 which.max(ev1dens$y)
#[1] 326
 abline(v=326)  #
```

Now (since luckily the densities are unimodal) it is a matter of sorting the normalized density values in decreasing order and finding the index at which the cumsum becomes > the target proportion:

```
 which(cumsum(ev1dens$y[ order(ev1dens$y, decreasing =TRUE) ])/sum(ev1dens$y) > 0.9)[1]
#[1] 124
 ev1dens$x[order(ev1dens$y, decreasing =TRUE) ][124]
#1] 240.6612
```

I made an effort at determining where the cutpoint would be set for a 90% inclusion but after looking at [Tommy's answer to your follow-on question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8540143/add-consecutive-elements-of-a-vector-until-a-value), my concerns about the accuracy of this method are amplified. 124 would be the index for a cutpoint capturing 90%, and 240 would be the x value. Look at the plotted sequence of descending ev1dens$y values traversed during the cumsum process plotted in dashed red,  and the green vertical line where the 90% level is eventually  accumulated:

```
 ev1dens <-  density(dfrm$tm, weights=dfrm$ev1/sum(dfrm$ev1), from=0, to=364)
 which(cumsum(ev1dens$y[ order(ev1dens$y, decreasing =TRUE) ])/sum(ev1dens$y) > 0.9)[1]
# [1] 175
 ev1dens$x[order(ev1dens$y, decreasing =TRUE) ][175]
# [1] 240.0548
 idx <- order(ev1dens$y, decreasing =TRUE)
  lines(ev1dens$x[idx], ev1dens$y[idx], lty=3, lwd=2.5, col="red")
  abline(v=240, col="green", lwd=3)
```

[image]

You can examine the joint distribution of tm and the two vectors.

```
  require(hexbin)
 hexev1 <- with(dfrm,  hexbin(tm, ev1))
 plot(hexev1)
 hexev2 <- with(dfrm,  hexbin(tm, ev2))
 plot(hexev2)
 plot(hexev1)
```

The index to get to x% of the total (which I think is quite different that the clustering above is just:

```
> min(which(cumsum(ev1) >= sum(ev1)*(x/100) ) )
[1] 317
> min(which(cumsum(ev2) >= sum(ev2)*(x/100) ) )
[1] 112
```

Comment: What you present is descriptives of the event duration. This is not what i mention. I need a "density" measure of the days till a x % of the total annual event duration is obtained.

Comment: You will need to define what you mean by 'density' since it is not what the standard use to the term is. The std-deviation of ev2 is less than the std-deviation of ev1 so you will also need to define what you mean by "focussed". And: Do you intend that the days be consecutive?

Comment: Bad form to downvote an answer just because you don't understand it!

Comment: Thats why i placed the term "density" and "focused" in bracket. Take a loot at the two plots I mention in my question. This will give you a feeling about the temporal aggregation of the event durations, much more focused in ev1 (the total annual duration is achieved in less days) much more focused in ev2 (the total annual event duration is achieved in much more days)

Comment: Carl: Please read my question more carefully. I totally get what you and DWin write. Its not what I asked however.

Comment: I think I finally understand what you want.

Comment: Dwin: Your modified post is a very elegant approach. What does the highlighted region the curve present? Thank you for your efforts.

Comment: It's not so much the area that is being highlighted as the path one is taking in sequentially traversing  the density values in decreasing order. The I suppose if I had made that path green You would also have been able to see it following the left-hand side of the density curve.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. If i understand correctly your graph, you plot relatively how much (y axis) each observation day (x-axis) contributes to the total event duration, right?  In your graph, how can you plot or highlight the location of the minimum day interval where a x % of event of the total event duration occurs? Thank you again for your efforts.

Comment: I'll post what I did, but I don't think it yields the correct answer after looking at Tommy's answer to your follow-on question.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you want it a temporal standard deviation. You could calculate the mean time weighted by observation (or median, using the code in DWin's answer with x = 50), then take the square root of the mean squared difference weighted by observation. (Using DWin's dataframe and code)

```
t.med <- min(which(cumsum(ev1) >= sum(ev1)*(.5)))
t.sd <- with(dfrm, sqrt(mean(((tm - t.med) * ev1)^2)))
```

This yields 174031 for `ev1` and 41416 for `ev2`.

As alternate statistics, both the proportion of non-zero measurements and the length of the longest consecutive run with non-zero measurements divided by total length both are very simple, easy to understand, and seem to get your point across.

Comment: @ECII I see that this `t.med` is not a useful statistic to you in itself, but it is the temporal median of the observations, hence a decent center for a standard deviation. All it's being used for is a location parameter. And a standard deviation is nice standard way to characterize spread. The statistic you describe in the question could be sensitive to your percent, e.g. `rep(1, 100)` and `c(rep(0, 19), rep(90 / 80, 80), 10)` would evaluate as very similar if your percent is much greater than 10.