# Add consecutive elements of a vector until a value

Tags: r

I would like to calculate the minimum number of consecutive elements in a vector that when added (consecutively) would be less than a given value.

For example in the following vector

```
ev<-c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2.7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3.27, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 370.33, 1375.4, 
1394.03, 1423.8, 1360, 1269.77, 1378.8, 1350.37, 1425.97, 1423.6, 
1363.4, 1369.87, 1365.5, 1294.97, 1362.27, 1117.67, 1026.97, 
1077.4, 1356.83, 565.23, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 356.83, 
973.5, 0, 240.43, 1232.07, 1440, 1329.67, 1096.87, 1331.37, 1305.03, 
1328.03, 1246.03, 1182.3, 1054.53, 723.03, 1171.53, 1263.17, 
1200.37, 1054.8, 971.4, 936.4, 968.57, 897.93, 1099.87, 876.43, 
1095.47, 1132, 774.4, 1075.13, 982.57, 947.33, 1096.97, 929.83, 
1246.9, 1398.2, 1063.83, 1223.73, 1174.37, 1248.5, 1171.63, 1280.57, 
1183.33, 1016.23, 1082.1, 795.37, 900.83, 1159.2, 992.5, 967.3, 
1440, 804.13, 418.17, 559.57, 563.87, 562.97, 1113.1, 954.87, 
883.8, 1207.1, 1046.83, 995.77, 803.93, 1036.63, 946.9, 887.33, 
727.97, 733.93, 979.2, 1176.8, 1241.3, 1435.6)
```

What is the minimum number of elements that when added consecutively (as in the order within the vector) would sum up to lets say 20000

To be more clear i need the following: 
Start with ev[1] and add consecutively up to 20000. Record the number of elements you had to add in order to get to 20000 as r[1]. Then start with ev[2] and add till 20000 and so on. Recored the number of elements you had to add till 20000 as r[2]. Do this for the entire length of ev. Then return the min(r)

For example

`j<-c(1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 9, 2)`.

I want the minimum number of elements that when added consecutively would give lets say >20. This should be `3` (5+7+9)

Thanks a lot

Comment: This is really a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8539303/time-series-density-of-measurement

Comment: No its not. Its just an attempt to come arround some problems and answer my previous question

Comment: Don't you want to find the minimum consecutive sequence of numbers that sum to 20000? Consider `c(1,2,19999,0,0,55)`. Your stated algorithm would answer `3` (1,2,19999) instead of `2` (2,19999)?

Comment: Tommy: The answer would be 2 in the example you mention. Can you help me programm it?

Comment: @ECII - Well OK, since it's Friday ;-)

Comment: I see you updated your explanation...but note that `7+9+2` < 20 ;-)

Comment: As you said...Friday night... lol  ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, I'll give it a shot: This one will find the length of the minimum sequence of numbers 
that add up to or above `max`. It makes no claims to be fast, but it has `O(2n)` time complexity :-)

I made it return both the start index and the length.

```
f <- function(x, max=10) {
  s <- 0
  len <- Inf
  start <- 1
  j <- 1
  for (i in seq_along(x)) {
     s <- s + x[i]
     while (s >= max) {
       if (i-j+1 < len) {
         len <- i-j+1
         start <- j
       }
       s <- s - x[j]
       j <- j + 1
     }
  }

  list(start=start, length=len)
  # uncomment the line below if you don't need the start index...
  #len
}

r <- f(ev, 20000) # list(start=245, length=15)
sum(ev[seq(r$start, len=r$length)]) # 20275.42

# Test speed:
x <- sin(1:1e6)

system.time( r <- f(x, 1.9) ) # 1.54 secs

# Compile the function makes it 9x faster...
g <- compiler::cmpfun(f)
system.time( r <- g(x, 1.9) ) # 0.17 secs
```

Comment: @Dason and ECII - Thanks, but it's just a for-loop ;-)

Comment: @Tommy is it possible to modify the function so that it can recieve a vector of values as max and output a vector of values corresponding to each value of max?

Answer (score 2):

```
library(zoo) # Needed for rollapply
N <- 20000 # The desired sum we want to achieve
j <- 0
for(i in 1:length(ev)){
    k <- rollapply(ev, i, sum)
    j[i] <- max(k)
    if(j[i] >= N){
        break
    }
}
i # contains how many consecutive elements you need to sum (15)
j[i] # contains the corresponding sum(20275.42)
```

Currently this doesn't tell you where the specific subset occurs in the vector but another use of rollapply could get you that information.

There are other ways to do it but if you have a really long vector this will break out of the loop so you don't calculate more than you need.  The basic idea is to use rollapply to create a vector of the consecutive sums of length k and then find the maximum of that.  If this is less than what we desire do the same thing for sums of length k+1.  Repeat until we find a sum that is larger than the desired threshold.

Edit:

This appears to be about 100x faster.  I haven't compared it to Tommy's answer (which is probably faster than this but this will provide a significant speedup compared to my original method.

Edit 2: Moving the [-n] and removing the suppresswarnings speeds this up quite a bit.

```
myfun <- function(ev, N){
    i <- 1
    n <- length(ev)
    j <- ev
    repeat{
        j <- (j[-n] + ev[-c(1:i)])
        i <- i+1
        n <- n-1
        if(max(j) >= N | i > length(ev)){
            break;
        }
    }
    return(i)
}

myfun(ev, 20000)

# And stealing the idea from Tommy gives a nice speedup as well
myfuncomp <- compiler:cmpfun(myfun)
myfuncomp(ev, 20000)
myfunc3 <- compiler:cmpfun(myfun, options = list(optimize = 3))
myfunc3(ev, 20000)

library(rbenchmark) # For testing
# If you have Tommy's functions loaded as f and g you can compare
benchmark(f(ev, 20000), g(ev, 20000), myfun(ev, 20000), myfuncomp(ev, 20000), myfunc3(ev, 20000))
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what i needed. Unfortunately its painfully slow for large vectors. Thanks again.

Comment: @ECII I would recommend accepting the answer Tommy gave.  It's a lot nicer and they mentioned compiling it which makes it very fast.

Comment: I edited the second version to make it faster.  Testing it on my machine has this being slightly faster than Tommy's and compiling with optimize = 3 gives the best out of all the methods I tried.

Comment: @Dason your answer give different intial values than Tommy. Any ideas why? :  

df<-data.frame(perc=seq(1, sum(ev),10), tommy=NA, dason=NA)

for (i in 1:dim(df)[1]){
  df$tommy[i]<-my.fun.tommy(ev, df$perc[i])
  df$dason[i]<-my.fun.dason(ev, df$perc[i])
}

df$agree<-as.numeric(df$tommy==df$dason)
sum(df$tommy==df$dason)
df<-df[df$agree==0,]

Comment: @ECII  not at the moment. That answer is like 8 years old. Maybe I'll look back on Monday.

Answer (score 0):

you mean something like this?

```
> sum(ifelse(cumsum(ev)<=200000, 1, 0))
[1] 364
```

Comment: No. Let me explain better. What i want is: Start with ev[1] and add consecutively  up to 20000. Record the number of elements you had to add in order to get to 20000 as r[1]. Then start with ev[2] and add till 20000 and so on. Recored the number of elements you had to add till 20000 as r[2]. Do this for the entire length of ev. Then return  the min(r)

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be a Traveling Salesman Problem in disguise unless you put in some more constraints. You cannot necessarily start at the max ev and go out in either direction since it may be a local non-dense maximum

```
x=1:length(ev)
 plot(x,ev)
 lxy <- loess(ev~x )
 lines(predict(lxy, x=1:length(y)))
 title(main="loess() fit of ev")
```

[image]

But in the region of the most dense values the values are fairly flat.

```
 x=1:length(y); y=c(356.83, 
 973.5, 0, 240.43, 1232.07, 1440, 1329.67, 1096.87, 1331.37, 1305.03, 
 1328.03, 1246.03, 1182.3, 1054.53, 723.03, 1171.53, 1263.17, 
 1200.37, 1054.8, 971.4, 936.4, 968.57, 897.93, 1099.87, 876.43, 
 1095.47, 1132, 774.4, 1075.13, 982.57, 947.33, 1096.97, 929.83, 
 1246.9, 1398.2, 1063.83, 1223.73, 1174.37, 1248.5, 1171.63, 1280.57, 
 1183.33, 1016.23, 1082.1, 795.37, 900.83, 1159.2, 992.5, 967.3, 
 1440, 804.13, 418.17, 559.57, 563.87, 562.97, 1113.1, 954.87, 
 883.8, 1207.1, 1046.83, 995.77, 803.93, 1036.63, 946.9, 887.33, 
 727.97, 733.93, 979.2, 1176.8, 1241.3, 1435.6)

 lxyhi <- loess(y~x)
 plot(x,y)
 lines(predict(lxyhi, x=1:length(y)))
```

[image]

Comment: nice graphs... But since the stated problem is to find *consecutive numbers* that add up to a value, I don't see why it would be an NP-complete problem (as the travelling salesman is).

Comment: Trying to define the region is not easy. Where you should be extending the index of the interval cannot be determined without a global search.

Comment: I must admit to being a bit lost here - I'm not a statistician, but the way I see the problem (and the way I solved it) was with a (rather) simple for-loop. Are you saying that that algorithm is wrong? If so, I'd like to understand the circumstances where it fails!

Comment: I don't think not being a statistician (which I'm not either) is a problem. I was just saying you needed to a global search, but I guess yours is, and it out-performs my effort to apply a density()-based strategy. + to you.